# jQuery Dragging in Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, drag-and-drop

I'm working on a project where you can drag around icons. When you drag the icon, the actual icon is hidden, and you just drag a placeholder. This works great in Firefox, but doesn't always work well in Chrome. If you start dragging to quickly, the cursor turns into the 'prevent' symbol, and the placholder stops moving.

Demo: http://184.75.250.123/cloud/

Code:

HTML

```
<li class="item" draggable="false">
    <a class="app">
        <img src="[imgurl]" class="icon" draggable="false" />
        <span class="name">Facebook</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

and

```
<div id="proxy"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$('#section-home ul.app-page li.item').live('mousedown', function(){
    var item = $(this);
    $(window).mousemove(function(e){
        item.addClass('isdragging');
        $('#proxy').css({top: e.pageY+'px', left: e.pageX+'px'});
    });
});
$(window).mouseup(function(){
    $('#section-home ul.app-page li.item').removeClass('isdragging');
    $(window).unbind("mousemove");
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: For some reason it seems to work fine isolated.  http://jsfiddle.net/N7vpk/  Maybe it's some conflict with something else on the page.

Comment: @JamesMontagne That's weird, thanks for noticing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I was using an `<img />` tag as a background, and since images are draggable by default, if I started moving the mouse too fast, I'd start dragging the background.

The background image:

```
<div id="background">
    <img src="images/calm_main_bg.jpg" />
</div>
```

What I did to fix it:

```
<div id="background">
    <img src="images/calm_main_bg.jpg" draggable="false" />
</div>
```

Thanks James for telling me that it worked isolated.